# How to make your child div width equal to height of parent?

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a solution in css only.

I am creating a sidebar where i have a large text in a div.

Now i want that when my rotated `text` becomes large then it should start from the bottom and at last it should have ellipses also if `div` should be responsive

What I did:
I have created a sample for it but it is not starting from bottom with ellipses at last and also not responsive because parent height is dynamic so i need to set child width same as parent so that it will be inside parent. since it is rotated text child width should be parent height.

```css
.float-sidebar {
  height: 100%; // here height is dynamic but it is not in px 
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.vertical-text:after {
  content: "...";
  float: left;
  margin-top: 100%;
}

.vertical-text {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: translate(0, 50%) rotate(-90deg);
  /* change this */
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  color: grey;
}

.vertical-text>span {
  /* add a span for true centring */
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100%; // when height changes of parent then it should change as well
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sidebar-main:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white, #a6a6a6)
}

.sidebar-main:active {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white, #989898)
}

.sidebar-main {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white, lightgrey);
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="float-sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-main">
    <div class="vertical-text">
      <span>start as das d sa dsa ds ad sa dsa d sad sa d sa d adasdasdsad s ssa  sad sa dsa d sa dsa d sad sadsadas </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/tH2LtCnR3yHzXpSEeQan?p=preview

Comment: And how do you intend it to turn?

Comment: sorry didn't got you but my problem is just need to set the child div width which is in parent height width... it is already turned but i need to set it from the bottom.. and hr bottom part is done but when i change the height of parent then i need to change the child div so that i will be remain start from bottom

Comment: do yo mean "vertical-text" div height to 100%?

Comment: not too sur what you want in the end, to write text on the side, you may take a look at writing-mode, to set an height or a max-height, is also an issue but will matter from the rest of the code and content around used. with max-height:xxvh and writing-mode, you could something do looking alike what you want : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/NzZwZO but i guess it won't fit with the rest of your page

Comment: @G-Cyr thanks but writing-mode does not support ie.also its alternative tb-rl is deprecated

Comment: If you refer to IE, i guess you mean IE11 and below, which hurts as much as prefix for webkit, mobile IE or Firefox. depreciated for obsolete browser still running is not an issue to me ;) . the funny thing is that IE5/6 already had the writing-mode option , which was a way (among other) to set the "haslayout" .  Do you have an example that shows how height is set  (padding-top margin-top:100% is usefull to shape a square from width) ... is this what you want or is height meant to be set from contents standing aside ?

Comment: i will create a proper example and will post it soon, however i have gone thorugh the side of developer mozilla where i found that tb-rl is deprecated and should not be used. i know it is working for now but who know when it will be removed.. so i have not implemented it through tb-rl,, but i will post a proper exmple to find a solution @G-Cyr

Comment: here is the example @G-Cyr can we make the text rorate without using writing-mode here?

Comment: You can rotate the text container  with transform, but you also want height to  adapt and ellipsis. writing-mode is no trick so it is easy to implement the ellipsis overflow for the text. to set the height is then another problem where text direction doesn't matter. But Once rotated via transform, the rotation is only visual ... the height is actually the width . Javascript or some tricks are needed to update the width and values which are at screen the opposite . width for height, height for width .....

Comment: @G-Cyr exactly this is my problem, but I don't want to use JavaScript isn't there any  solution in css?

Comment: Do you have a full example of your sidebar aside some contents, i still do not see what or how height is to be set . Is it a static height or is it interacting with what is aside ? If it is from a square, then it's easy width equals height ... but obviously not the case here ;)